# How to check for an OPTIONS method call in a java servlet filter?

Tags: java, servlets, jetty, servlet-filters

I have a servlet filter, in which if the call is OPTIONS method call, then a specific set of task needs to be done.

Is there a way I can check my custom filter , which as of now , extends javax.servlet.filter, if an incoming http request is a request for an OPTIONS call??

Thanks

PS:Im using jetty as my app server.

Comment: @Jigar: Http method that returns  what          methods supports the server.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`getMethod` in HttpServletRequest is maybe what you need: http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest.html#getMethod()

It should return `OPTIONS` in case of an `OPTIONS` request.

Answer (score 0):

You must implement `doOptions()` method.

Comment: This is correct for [HTTPServlet](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServlet.html), though not for [Servlet Filters](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/Filter.html)